# Jcarousel highlight the first visible photo

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

Here is one little tougher challenge.

Click my jsfiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qUKrm/):

I am using this [jQuery plugin](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarouse) for an album. I want to highlight the item whenever user click the pic. It is done !

below is the function to trigger the album:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />-->
<style>
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 1px solid #346F97;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 40px;

}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    width: 75px;
    height: 245px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 300px;
    height: 75px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}/*
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-placeholder {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
} */

/**
 *  Horizontal Buttons
 */
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/next-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    left: 5px;
    right: auto;
    background-image: url(http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/prev-horizontal.png);
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:focus {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:active {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:focus,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    background-position: -96px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/prev-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
    background-image: url(next-horizontal.png);
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:hover, 
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:focus {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:active {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:focus,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll:2,
        animation:'slow',
        wrap:'last',
        initCallback:function(){
             $("#mycarousel li:eq(0)").css('border','2px solid gray');
            }
     });

     $("#mycarousel li").click(function(){
         $("#mycarousel li").css('border','none');
         $(this).css('border','2px solid gray');
     });

     });
</script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, What I want is that Whenever user clicks the next or previous arrow, First visigble item should be highlighted with border.

Can use proper configuration to function to get this done ? Below is link for the plugin docs
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

Comment: jcarousel and the css file cannot be load on jsfiddle..

Comment: @MateiMihai, It can be :) Please Check the example in jsfiddle.

Comment: Maybe you can .. but I don't `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js on this server.`. And the plugin is not working because of that

Comment: +1 yup. I saw. Can you please add js and css in blank html page on your machine to see this working plugin ?

Comment: @MateiMihai, Please get the whole html in question.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a user-defined class `current` for the image which is highlighted, and managed the highlighting of the next or previous images, based on the element which has this `current` class, using 2 more click events, of next and prev buttons.

Here is the working script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll:2,
        animation:'slow',
        wrap:'last',
        initCallback:function(){
             $("#mycarousel li:eq(0)").css('border','2px solid gray');
     $("#mycarousel li:eq(0)").addClass("current");
         }
     });

     $("#mycarousel li").click(function(){
         $("#mycarousel li").css('border','none');
     $("#mycarousel li").removeClass('current');
         $(this).css('border','2px solid gray');
     $(this).addClass('current');
     });

 $(".jcarousel-next-horizontal").click(function(){
    $(".current").css('border', 'none');
    $(".current").next().css('border', '2px solid gray');
    $(".current").removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
 });
 $(".jcarousel-prev-horizontal").click(function(){
    $(".current").css('border', 'none');
    $(".current").prev().css('border', '2px solid gray');
    $(".current").removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
 });
  });
```